# Conceptually Understanding the Mathematical Definition for an Envelope of Family of Curves

Tags: partial-differential-equations, intuition, curves, envelope

Assuming we have a one-parameter, two-dimensional, family of curves, given by $f(x, y, p) = 0$, there are two requirements for the envelope (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)#) of that family (assuming it exists):

$$\begin{Bmatrix} &f(x, y, p) &= &0& \\ &\frac{\partial}{\partial p}  \left[f(x, y, p)\right]&= &0&\end{Bmatrix}$$

Now, this first requirement makes sense, as the envelope curve must itself sit on a point from the family of curves.
But I'm having trouble conceptually wrapping my mind around this second requirement and what it *means*.

Comment: Can you give an explicit example?

Comment: @TegLouis, let's use $y - \sin(px) = 0$, which has the obvious envelope of $y = \pm 1$ (though I am currently struggling to actually prove that). My question is mainly about why differentiating with respect to the parameter makes sense. As an example of the conceptual argument I am looking for, if we are looking for a local extrema, we differentiate with respect to the independent variable in order to find a zero, *because the slope at the local min/max will be zero*.

Comment: I understand now. Envelope can mean different things in math. So, now which one is clear. Thanks.

Comment: Each $p$ defines a curve. The idea is to find the intersection of the curve defined by $p$ and a "nearby" one defined by $p+h$, where $h$ is small. Can you see how that leads to the partial derivative?

Comment: @ChrisLewis, this is what I had been thinking, but I guess I was wondering if there was some particular example that would make this immediately obvious. For some reason, I wasn't wrapping my mind around it right.

Comment: You can find this question addressed in a number of posts on this site. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/401822/necessary-equation-for-envelopes/402038#402038) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4716014/an-ambiguous-definition-of-envelopes-with-reference-to-differential-equations-an/4716260#4716260) are a few answers I've written on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most text books which over this Concept generally hand-wave or gloss-over the mathematics behind the Equations.

Yes , I agree with OP that it is not very clear why $ \frac{\partial f(x,y,p)} {\partial p} $ must be $0$.

Eg , the given wiki brushes-off the Issue by claiming $f(x,y,p_1)=0$ &  $f(x,y,p_2)=0$ , hence $f(x,y,p_1)-f(x,y,p_2)=0$ & almost "magically" , it concludes that $\frac{f(x,y,p_1)-f(x,y,p_2)}{(p_1-p_2)}=0$ , which is not intuitive : (1) Why not divide by $(p_1-p_2)^2$ ? (2) Why not say the Same for Elementary Differential Calculus to claim that $dy/dx=0$ always ? (3) Why not consider $\frac{\partial f} {\partial x} = 0$ with Same logic ? (4) Why 2 Criteria are enough ?
In short , the given Derivation is incomplete or inaccurate.

It is similar in most other text books too.

**I will try to give my intuition & then I will give the Correct Derivation.

Best (Complete) Derivation I came across was in Myskis (Mir Publishers) "Introductory Mathematics for Engineers" & my Elaboration (Calculation) will be utilizing that.

It may look a little too long but it is essential very simple.**

[image: ENVELOPE]

Consider the Black Envelope & the Grey Isolated Curve & the family of Curves which have that Envelope.

When the left-most Grey curve is intersecting on the left (Point $A$) , the tangents (to the curve & to the Envelope) are Positive but not equal.
At the Intersection on the right (Point $B$) , one tangent is going up while the other is going down.
Naturally , we can see that the Grey Curve can not have the Envelope shown at that Point.
Let us ignore the Grey Curve , which is not in the family of curves & is shown to high-light what the tangents must be like.

Consider the right-most Purple curve.
The tangent to Envelope & the tangent to Curve are coinciding , having Exact Same value at $E$ , the Point of Contact.
This is what we want from 2 Consecutive Curves.

Consider the Central Blue Curve corresponding to some $p$.
To the left , we have the Curve corresponding to $p - \delta p$.
To the right , we have the Curve corresponding to $p + \delta p$.

The Points of Intersection are $C$ & $D$ which lie on the Curves hence $f(x,y,p)=0$.
$C$ : Intersection of $f(x,y,p - \delta p)=0$ & $f(x,y,p)=0$
$D$ : Intersection of $f(x,y,p)=0$ & $f(x,y,p + \delta p)=0$
We can not make $\delta p \equiv 0$ , because all Points between 2 Curves will be Common.
When $\delta p$ tends to $0$ , the Points $C$ & $D$ get closer to the Envelope & will eventually lie on the Envelope.
Here , hand-waving intuition :  $f(x,y,p + \delta p) - f(x,y,p) \equiv 0$ , $\frac{f(x,y,p + \delta p) - f(x,y,p)}{\delta p} \equiv 0$ , hence we can "eliminate" $\delta p$ by taking limit when it tends to $0$

**Derivation (utilizing material given by Myskis) :**

We have $f(x,y,p) = 0$ on the Curves & on the Envelope.
Let $p=C$ , some value , corresponding to a Point on the Envelope , hence $f(x,y,C) = 0$.

Let $y_{envel}(x)$ be the Envelope , while $y_{curv}(x)$ be the Curve at the Point we are focussing on here.

When we **move along the Envelope** (varying the $x$ co-ordinate) , naturally $C$ will change , that is , $C=C(x)$
Partially Differentiate the given function to get :
$\color{blue}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy_{envel}}{dx}} + \color{green}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial C} \frac{dC(x)}{dx}} = 0 \tag{1}$
When we **move along the Curve** (varying the $x$ co-ordinate) , we keep $C$ Constant , that is , $\frac{dC}{dx}=0 \tag{2}$
Partially Differentiate the given function to get :
$\color{blue}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{dy_{curv}}{dx}} + \color{red}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial C} \frac{dC}{dx}} = 0 \tag{3}$

At the Point of Contact between Curve $y_{curv}(x)$ & Envelope $y_{envel}(x)$ , we want the two tangents to be Equal , that is , $\frac{dy_{curv}}{dx}=\frac{dy_{envel}}{dx} \tag{4}$ , which will Equalize the 2 blue Parts in (1) & (3)

In (3) , the red Part is $0$ , hence the remaining blue Part is $0$.
We can plug that into (1) to make the green Part $0$.

In general , We know $C(x)$ is not a Constant in green Part , hence we are left with $ \frac {\partial f} {\partial C} = 0 $

**Thus we got what we wanted : $\frac {\partial f} {\partial p} = 0 $**

Most text books avoid the Elaborate Details & simply hand-wave to give the Criteria. The exception is Myskis who has given the Details.

Answer (score 1):

I won't be adding anything else to the previous answers but a piece of imagination and loose interpretations to bring a physical intuition about.

**A moving point running along the envelope**

If you look carefully the animation of an sliding bar on the [envelope page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of the wikipedia, you'll agree with me, we can think of the envelope as a rail $\Gamma(x)$ guiding a moving point.

Lets such point $x$ be parameterized by $t$ $|$ $x=x(t)$ and $\Gamma(x(t))$.

The derivative,

$$ \Gamma'(x(t)) = \frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} $$

The mobile point actually exists within a family of curves $ y = C(x,t)$ so the differential of its movement is,

$$ dC(x,t) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} dt $$

Diving by $dt$,

$$ \frac{dC(x,t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} \frac{dt}{dt} $$

Or simply,

$$ \frac{dC(x,t)}{dt} = \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} $$

Since $C$ and $\Gamma$ are coincident for the moving point, $ y = C = \Gamma $, at that particular point,

$$ \frac{\partial\Gamma}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} =  \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} $$

So, $ \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} $ has to equal 0 at that point.

The first meaning I can think of for the derivative condition equaling $0$ is:

*Meaning 1*

> The approximation point behaves like a composed movement.

**Base & Roulette on an elastic band**

Observing the same animation on the wikipedia we can also deduce that the family of curves kind of rotate around the approximation (contact) point. We cannot speak about a rigid solid but its similar to a stationary node in the solution of a partial differential equation.

When looking at the differential of a family of curves,

$$ dC(x,t) = \frac{\partial C}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial C}{\partial t} dt $$

we can interpret it as a movement in the same curve (the $dx$ part), and a movement due to the shape shifting (the $dy$ part).

A point would be "stationary" if it shares it's tangent vector with the adjacent curve in the family. To put it another terms, there is point movement ($\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}$) but not surface shaking ($\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$)

So the derivative condition implies some extra meanings,

*Meaning 2*

> The envelope is the locus of the "stationary node" of a family of curves.

*Meaning 3*

> The envelope is the locus of all the common adjacent tangents of a family of curves.

Notice that two curves sharing a tangent vector don't slide one upon the other.

*Meaning 4*

> The envelope is the surface that the curve family rolls upon without sliding.

**A beautiful video**

PhysicsGrad made this beautiful video showing the curve family in 3D and gives a mathematical explanation of why the derivative has to be 0 using Rolle's theorem.

https://youtu.be/akF6NoIErus?si=zFpwFxTsEEE5BdSS

I hope it helps you on grasping an intuitive sense on what is going around this subject.